# How to deserialize the following JSON to get the list of values?

Tags: apex, json, callout, deserialize

I have used the code below to deserialize the json but throwing an error.

`Map<String,Object> root =(Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody()));`

> "Callout error Invalid conversion from runtime type `List<ANY>` to `Map<String,ANY>`"

I want to deserialize the JSON using an apex class to get the list of values?

```
{
   "controllerValues": {},
   "defaultValue": null,
   "eTag" : "",
   "url" : "",
   "values" : [
    {
            "attributes": null,
            "label": "PicklistValue1",
            "validFor": [],
            "value": "PicklistValue1"
    },
    {
            "attributes": null,
            "label": "PicklistValue2",
            "validFor": [],
            "value": "PicklistValue2"
    }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message:

> Callout error Invalid conversion from runtime type List to Map

suggests that the JSON in the body you are receiving is a list i.e. starts with `[` and ends with `]`.

If the data is a list, change to e.g.:

```
List<Object> root = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
```

Comment: I have used Json2 Apex to deserialize the above mentioned JSON but while parsing I'm getting the error "Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object"

Comment: @user69684 Sounds like the same problem.  The incoming JSON is an array of objects (that starts with `[`) at its root not an object (that starts with `{`) at its root. See e.g. http://json.org/.

Comment: when I used this List<Object> root = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody()); it is saying illegal assignment from map to list .I have used Json2Apex to desereialize but facing the same issue

Comment: @user69684 If you have following code, that could be generating the error. To make your question clear, post the code that is doing the parsing and a unit test case that reproduces the error.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265642/malformed-json-expected-at-the-beginning-of-object-while-deserializing-json