# Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object while deserializing JSON..!

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

For this JSON When I tried to serialize using the class generated from json2Apex I am getting the error "Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object"

JSON:

```
{
       "controllerValues": {},
       "defaultValue": null,
       "eTag" : "",
       "url" : "",
       "values" : [
        {
            "attributes": null,
                "label": "PicklistValue1",
                "validFor": [],
                "value": "PicklistValue1"
        },
        {
            "attributes": null,
                "label": "PicklistValue2",
                "validFor": [],
                "value": "PicklistValue2"
        }
       ]
    }
```

Apex:

```
public class casePicklistItemWrapper {

    public ControllerValues controllerValues;
    public Object defaultValue;
    public String eTag;
    public String url;
    public List<Values> values;

    public class Values {
        public Object attributes;
        public String label;
        public List<ControllerValues> validFor;
        public String value;
    }

    public class ControllerValues {
    }

    public static casePicklistItemWrapper parse(String json) {
        return (casePicklistItemWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, casePicklistItemWrapper.class);
    }
}
```

class logic to process the json result

```
List<selectOption> result = new List<selectOption>();
        string jsonResult = res.getBody();
        casePicklistItemWrapper arenaPLMItemObject = casePicklistItemWrapper.parse(jsonResult); 
        List<casePicklistItemWrapper.values> caseSelectedpicklistbyRt   = arenaPLMItemObject.values;

        for(casePicklistItemWrapper.values PickVal: caseSelectedpicklistbyRt){
            result.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(PickVal.value),String.valueOf(PickVal.label)));
        }
        return result;
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the JSON? Is it in fact valid, well-formed, and having an object at the top level?

Comment: the JSON is the output from the user interface API containing the picklists values specific to a record type

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the jsonResult string variable to confirm is an actual valid JSON. It must start with the curly braces, otherwise it's not valid JSON.
You could do a System.debug(res.getBody()); before assigning that to the variable and check the debug logs to see it's content.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that because your "defaultValue" & "attributes" variables in your wrapper are of the Object type, you will need to specify them as objects in your JSON rather than set them to null:

```
{
   "controllerValues": {},
   "defaultValue": {},
   "eTag" : "",
   "url" : "",
   "values" : [
    {
        "attributes": {},
        "label": "PicklistValue1",
        "validFor": [],
        "value": "PicklistValue1"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {},
        "label": "PicklistValue2",
        "validFor": [],
        "value": "PicklistValue2"
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: If you check the JSON in the question with JSONLint it is a valid JSON.

Comment: I did check it, but the fact it’s a valid JSON doesn’t mean Salesforce will successfully be able to deserialise it into your wrapper. :-)